# View is flipped when being added as subview of UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiview-hierarchy

I am drawing a triangle on a `UIView` via `drawRect` and subsequently add this `UIView` as subview of the main view (`UIView`).

Very easy and it shows.

The problem occurs when I use an `UIImageView`.

`UIView` (main view) adding `UIImageView` as subview and with this`UIImageView` adding the `UIView` as subview onto which I draw the triangle.

Hierarchy:

```
[UIView] (main view; i.e. self.view)
      |
    [UIImageView] 
            |
         [UIView] (onto which drawing is)
```

View creations:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){{0.0, 0.0}, 320.0, 480.0}];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:...];

[self.view addSubview:imageView];

viewWithTriangle = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.bounds];
[imageView addSubview:viewWithTriangle];
```

The triangle is flipped vertically. The easy fix would be to flip the `UIView` vertically again, but I would like to know why adding the `UIView` as subview of `UIImageView` would cause this flip.

This doesn't occur if I add the view where the drawing is directly as subview of the main view.

Answer (score 0):

The UIImage's orientation likely bleeds into UIImageView's coordinate system at times. UIImageView is highly optimized to work with drawing UIImage's to the screen. UIImageView doesn't even invoke `drawRect`, for e.g.

Using a breakpoint, when you see this behavior, check the value of `imageView.image.imageOrientation`. Is it equal to anything other than `UIImageOrientationUp`? If so, you likely need to work with the fact that the UIImageView is "translating" some properties into the UIImage's "human preferred" coordinate system, instead of the image data's actual coodinate system.

I haven't personally tested this code or approach, as I do not add subviews to UIImageView's, but it's a likely problem. Please let us know if this helps diagnose it -- I'm very curious!

Comment: Definitely; shall report back once I tested it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know a way to get to this meta data properties of the image? Also, can you tell me a bit more about the human preferred coordinate system? Thanks.

Comment: If you just need the orientation, use `imageView.image.imageOrientation`. Getting all EXIF data is straightforward, but non-trivial (look up docs for `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex` and what you need to setup and following to extract the info). I made up "human coordinate system" -- all I really meant was some coordinate system that has a 0,0 point somewhere known, and "up is up, and down is down" in relation the the actual phone/screen/view. If UIImageView's coordinate system is changed by it's loaded UIImage w/ non-up orientation, then human-up *might* be image-left-or-right. *Might*.